# Covariance between two transformations

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, covariance

*Let $U \perp V$ two random variables such that
$\mathbb{P}(U=1)=\mathbb{P}(V=1)=\frac{1}{4}$ and $\mathbb{P}(U=-1)=\mathbb{P}(V=-1)=\frac{3}{4}$. Let $X=\frac{U}{V}$ and $Y=U+V$. Find:*

*a) the joint law of $(X,Y)$.*

*b) $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$.*

*c) If we have $50$ i.i.d. with the same law of $U$ ($U_{1},\ldots,U_{50}$), and $Z=U_{1}+\cdots+U_{50}$, what is the distribution of $Z$? And the value of $\mathbb{P}(Z\leq-10)$?*

---

For b) we have $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=E[XY]+\frac{1}{4}$. Now, how I find $E[XY]=E[E[XY|X=i]]=?$

For c)… Pitch dark.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Part of the problem specification seems to be missing. You introduce probabilities for $U$ and $V$ and then ask questions about $X$ and $Y$, which weren't introduced.

Comment: @joriki Thanks! I edited the question!

Comment: There's still not enough information in the question to answer it. You only have the marginal distributions of $U$ and $V$ and no information about their joint distribution, so you obviously can't determine the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ either. Perhaps you forgot to state an assumption that $U$ and $V$ are independent? Also, what is the "worth" of $Z$? This term is not in common use in English. It seems that neither "value", nor "expected value" fit, since you apply the term both to a random variable and to a probability.

Comment: @joriki Obviously $U _|_ V$. And for $Z$, i have to find the distribution of $Z$.

Comment: I don't see what's obvious about that. You can get the symbol $\perp$ using `\perp` (for "perpendicular"). Please edit that information into the question; the questions should be self-contained and people shouldn't have to read the comments to understand it. Also, you didn't answer my question what you mean by "worth".

Comment: @joriki I edited the question. Thanks again.

Comment: I made some formatting edits (`\operatorname`, `\ldots`, `\cdots`).

Comment: It seems that in the expression for $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$ you substituted the expected values of $U$ and $V$ instead of those of $X$ and $Y$? Or how does $\frac14$ come about?

Comment: @joriki $\mathbb{E}[X]=1\cdot \frac{10}{16}+(-1)\cdot \frac{6}{16}=4/16=\frac{1}{4}$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y]=0\cdot \frac{6}{16}+(-2)\cdot \frac{9}{16}=-1$.

Comment: I see, sorry, I should have checked that. Interesting coincidence that it's the same as for $U$ and $V$. By the way, there's a typo; I presume it should be $Y=U+V$ instead of $V=U+V$.

Comment: @joriki Edited again. Yes: $Y=U+V$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $U$ and $V$ are independent, there are four possibilities for the values of $(U,V)$ with probabilities 
$$
\mathbb P(U=-1, V=-1) = \frac34\cdot\frac34=\frac9{16}
$$
$$
\mathbb P(U=-1, V=1) = \frac34\cdot\frac14=\frac3{16}
$$
$$
\mathbb P(U=1, V=-1) = \frac14\cdot\frac34=\frac3{16}
$$
$$
\mathbb P(U=1, V=1) = \frac14\cdot\frac14=\frac1{16}
$$

Note that 
$$
(U=-1, V=-1)\quad \Longrightarrow \quad (X=1, Y=-2) 
$$
$$
(U=-1, V=1)\quad \Longrightarrow \quad (X=-1, Y=0)
$$
$$
(U=1, V=-1)\quad \Longrightarrow \quad (X=-1, Y=0)
$$
$$
(U=1, V=1)\quad \Longrightarrow \quad (X=1, Y=2)
$$
As you can see, there are three values for the pair $(X,Y)$ only: 
$$
\mathbb P(X=1, Y=-2) = \frac9{16}, \quad \mathbb P(X=-1, Y=0) = \frac6{16}, \quad \mathbb P(X=1, Y=2) = \frac1{16}.
$$
Return to (b): 
$$
\mathbb E[XY] = \sum_{i,j}x_iy_i\mathbb P(X=x_i,Y=y_j)= 1\cdot(-2) \cdot \frac9{16}+(-1)\cdot 0 \cdot \frac6{16} + 1\cdot 2 \cdot \frac1{16}
$$

For (c). You can transform every $U_i$ to a Bernoulli random variable with success probability $\frac14$ by $B_i=\frac{U_i+1}{2}$ or $U_i=2B_i-1$. And then 
$$
Z=U_1+\ldots+U_{50}=2(B_1+\ldots+B_{50})-50.
$$
The distribution of the sum of independent Bernoulli random variables $B_1+\ldots+B_{50}$ is binomial $B(50,\frac14)$. So every time when $B_1+\ldots+B_{50}=k$, $Z=2k-50$ with the same probability.